# Getting data attribute value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

My HTML:

```
<a data-color="yellow">Yellow </a>
<a data-color="red">Red</a>
<a data-color="black">Black</a>
```

How can I get the value for `data-action` ?

```
$('a[data-color]').click(function(event) { }
```

Thanks.

Comment: This should be pretty straight forward using `attr` method to get the value. is there something you have not mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
$('a[data-color]').click(function(event) { 
  const val = $(this).data('color');
  console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method is used to get/set attributes.

```
$('a[data-color]').click(function(event) {
  $(this).attr('data-color'); //jquery
  this.attributes['data-color'].value //javascript
});
```